# DateTime format returns the wrong format in VS Community Edition, but works fine in Professional Edition

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-standard, .net-5, vs-community-edition

Below is my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
            Console.Read();
        }
```

When we execute the above code in the Visual Studio Community Edition (16.9.4) then it returns **25-Apr-2021 21.35.02** instead of **25/Apr/2021 21:35:02**

If we execute the same code in the Visual Studio Professional Version (16.9.4) then it works fine. It always returns **25/Apr/2021 21:35:02**.

This issue happens with all project types like .net5, Core 3.1, .net standard framework, .net 4.5 (console, web, Xamarin, WPF AND Desktop Application).

Can someone guide on how to resolve this issue in the VS Community Edition?

Comment: `DateTime` has no format, it's a binary value. Visual Studio is just the editor, not the executable application. Finally, why do you assume the output is wrong? If your locale's date separator is `-`, that's what you'll get in the output

Comment: if I Execute same code in Professional Version in same machine, then its work fine. If same code if I execute in Community then Exception thrown while converting string to dt.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, read the code again, the code is formatting the date by passing a format in `ToString()` call. It is returning in different format than what is passed to it, which in my books is the definition of wrong in this case.

Comment: @MatJ you misunderstood the format string then. Tim Schmelter explains what happens - `/` is the date separator placeholder. It's replaced by the real placeholder specified by the user's locale when the code executes. In some countries, the date separator is `-`, in others it's `.`.  It's the same with `,`, the thousand separator and `.` the decimal separator.

Comment: @MatJ if I run `dt.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`  in Germany or Russia, I *expect* the date separator to be `.`, not `/`. In Russia I expect `25.апр..2021 17:13:09`. In Germany, `25.Apr..2021 17:14:33`. In Greece, `25/Απρ/2021 17:14:08`. The only unexpected thing is the two dots, but that's what the localized month abbreviation returns in Germany and Russia

Answer (score 1):

If you use `/` you are using the [custom format specifier /](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator) which does: replace it with the current culture's date-separator, which seems to be `-` in your case.

You have two options to prevent it, pass `InvariantCulture`:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Escape the format specifier by wrapping it in ticks `'`:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd'/'MMM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: But my question is why output is not common for Community Edition and Profession Edition. its work fine before few months.

Comment: @KapilDave: it's working fine if you see `-` instead of `/`. It doesnt depend on the visual studio verision. I guess you have a computer with Visual Studio Professional where the region settings are that `/` is the date separator not `-`. Am i right, are they on different computers?

Comment: I have installed both edition in same machine. I am working in same project from last 3 years. This issue occurs after updating 16.9.4. Entire application generates error. Before updating visual studio, its work fine.

Comment: As per my knowledge, if we write 

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")) then it should return 25/Apr/2021 21:35:02 ,

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Don't want to append CultureInfo.InvariantCulture or its don't dependent on region settings

Comment: Clarification given by Microsoft also.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @KapilDave no, that's not the case. I have fixed my broken link in my answer. Please read about the Format specifier /. It will work only if your current culture uses / as date separator(like in the US).

Comment: @KapilDave you misunderstood how formatting works. The **editors** you use to write your program don't affect how your program works. Visual Studio is just the editor. You'd get the same behavior if you used Notepad, vim or nano. The *same program* will behave differently if you use a localizable format string and run your program on different machines. Which is A Very Good Thing. If I run a program in Germany I expect to see the German date format, not the US format, and vice versa

Comment: But my question is if we upgrade visual studio version then suddenly this happens ? Please can you execute this code in Visual Studio 2019 (Version 10. something) then it return 25/Apr/2021 21:35:02, now updated to latest (Version 16.9.4) then it generate error.  Should its expected output ? Please note I had not modified any system setting or datetime format setting in my operating system. I am not blaming on Edition whether its Community or Professional Edition. Its look like some issue in rendering .toString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")